# Core Data and Grand Central Dispatch Internal Inconsistency

Tags: ios, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I am developing an iOS app using iOS 5.

I am having trouble using grand central dispatch to fill a view for a GMGridViewCell.

THe problem is not with the GridCell it self, but with the access to data in GCD.

Here is my code:

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    //NSLog(@"Creating view indx %d", index);

    CGSize size = [self sizeForItemsInGMGridView:gridView];

    GMGridViewCell *cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCell];

    if (!cell) 
    {
        cell = [[GMGridViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    }

    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    dispatch_queue_t fillCellQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Cell fetch queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fillCellQueue, ^{
        SearchGridViewCell *cellView = [UIView loadFromNib:@"SearchGridViewCell" owner:self];
        Item *item = [self.foundItems objectAtIndex:index];

        cellView.itemImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:item.image.thumb];

        cellView.itemNameLabel.text  = item.name; 

        cellView.brandImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:item.group3.image.thumb];

        Attribute *itemAttribute = [item.attributes objectAtIndex:0];
        cellView.attributeLabel.text  = [itemAttribute.name stringByAppendingFormat:@": "];
        [cellView.attributeLabel sizeToFit];

        cellView.itemAttributeValueLabel.text = itemAttribute.value;
        [cellView.itemAttributeValueLabel sizeToFit];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [cell addSubview:cellView];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(fillCellQueue);

    return cell;
}
```

When running the app I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'statement is still active'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1a1f052 0x35b3d0a 0x11cde0a 0x11cd58d 0x11f689f 0x11ec955 0x11d7df4 0x11f6418 0x11f3b62 0x11f3a57 0x11f316b 0x11f2f97 0x11f2b75 0x11f29f2 0x1236e10 0x51de7 0x44ab445 0x44acecf 0x44acd28 0x44ac4af 0x91442b24 0x914446fe)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** More info,

The first line that throws the exception:

```
cellView.itemImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:item.image.thumb];
```

And I believe the problem is from GCD because when I run this without GCD it works fine. But the scrolling of the grid is a bit sluggish, which is why I want to add GCD to it.

Comment: you need to add more details. where in the code is this crash occurring? How do you know the method above is the culprit?

Comment: @Rog I have added more info. Basically this works fine when not using GCD, but the scrolling is a bit sluggish.

Comment: You should also not dispatch_sync() to the main queue, you should submit all requests to that queue async (the behavior for the main queue isn't what you think it is).

Comment: @jkh Yeah, I figure you are right. I was trying something out before posting here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `self.foundItems`, which I'm guessing is the result of an `NSFetchRequest` request in another thread.  `NSManagedObject` cannot be passed between threads.  You have to fetch the objects in the same thread you're going to use it.

Comment: I believe that is it. I will look into this.

Comment: @chris, do I need to fetch one item for each cell? It makes my tableView sluggish.

Comment: @ValentinShamardin Your best bet is to just fetch the items in the same thread you'll be using it.

Comment: So if fetch will work for 2 minutes and you need to display the result in UI. How you will do it?) Request data in background is normal.